# Facebook wall post: Losing url params when redirecting to canvas app and requiring authentication -> mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, canvas

This is a very specific case, but I wanted to see if others are experiencing the same behavior.

I have a facebook app that has canvas and mobile counterparts.  If I create a post on the user's wall that redirects to the canvas page with url parameters, the parameters are getting lost if both (a) the user is on mobile and it redirects to the mobile web page, and (b) the user hasn't yet authenticated the app.

This is a working example, that works in the browser (going to canvas) but fails on mobile:

```
http://m.facebook.com/apps/pachelo-dev/?postID=ag1zfnBhY2hlbG8tZGV2cgwLEgRQb3N0GLHnAgw&ref=feed&refid=8&_ft_=qid.5738844063446447813%3Amf_story_key.323188824420731
```

The only paramter that gets through is:

> ref=feed

Has anyone experienced similar problems?  Again, this is only happening on mobile and for users not yet authenticated to the app.